# Model association calling in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this method for my actionmailer. But on the line `mail(to: @reservation.restaurant.user.email, subject: "Reservation Notification for #{@reservation.restaurant.res_name}")` I get an undefined method (NoMethodError) for restaurant. I really do not understand the chaining here. Can anyone help me?

```
class ReservationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    default from: 'kgan@kgapplications.com'

    def reservation_notification(reservation)
        @reservation = reservation
        mail(to: @reservation.restaurant.user.email, subject: "Reservation Notification for #{@reservation.restaurant.res_name}")
    end

    def reservation_edit(reservation)
        @reservation = reservation
        mail(to: @reservation.user.email, subject: "Reservation has been changed for #{@reservation.restaurant.res_name}")
    end

end

class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @reservation = Reservation.all
    end

    def show
        @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @reservation = @restaurant.reservations.build
    end

    def create
    if user_signed_in?
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @reservation = @restaurant.reservations.build(reservation_params)
      if @reservation.save
        ReservationMailer.reservation_notification(@reservation).deliver
        redirect_to restaurant_reservation_path(@reservation.restaurant_id, @reservation.reservation_id)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    else
      redirect_to new_owner_session_path
    end
    end

    def edit
        @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    if @reservation.update_attributes(reservation_params)
      flash.now[:notice] = "You have successfully updated #{@reservation.reservation_id.titleize}."
      redirect_to @reservation
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
    end

    def destroy
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @reservation.destroy
    flash.now[:notice] = "#{@reservation.reservation_id.titleize} has been deleted!"
    redirect_to reservations_url
    end

  private

  def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation).permit(:name, :email, :requested_date_time, :message).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end

end

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurants
    validates :name, :email, :requested_date_time, presence: true
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_address
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true

  validates :res_name, :res_description, :address_street1, :address_city, :address_state, :address_zipcode, :address_country, presence: true

  def set_contact_info
    "Phone: #{self[:number_phone]} Fax: #{self[:number_fax]} Email: #{self[:email]}".squish
  end

  def set_address
    address.squish
  end

  private

  def address
    "#{self[:address_street1]} #{self[:address_street2]} #{self[:address_city]} #{self[:address_state]} #{self[:address_zipcode]} #{self[:address_country]}"
  end

end

Started GET "/restaurants/3/reservations/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 02:51:48 -0500
Processing by ReservationsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"restaurant_id"=>"3"}
  Restaurant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"  WHERE "restaurants"."restaurant_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["restaurant_id", 3]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered reservations/_form.html.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered reservations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.3ms)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 8  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 11.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)


Started POST "/restaurants/4/reservations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 07:06:49 -0500
Processing by ReservationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3XKqwdNcRSTveqJ9n6ggiMQGwLWkoe0Jemx1+oGZvjw=", "reservation"=>{"name"=>"test", "email"=>"test@test.com", "requested_date_time(1i)"=>"2014", "requested_date_time(2i)"=>"7", "requested_date_time(3i)"=>"21", "requested_date_time(4i)"=>"07", "requested_date_time(5i)"=>"00", "message"=>"etetetetete"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "restaurant_id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 7  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Restaurant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "restaurants".* FROM "restaurants"  WHERE "restaurants"."restaurant_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["restaurant_id", 4]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "reservations" ("created_at", "email", "message", "name", "requested_date_time", "restaurant_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "reservation_id"  [["created_at", "2014-07-21 12:06:49.727918"], ["email", "test@test.com"], ["message", "etetetetete"], ["name", "test"], ["requested_date_time", "2014-07-21 07:00:00.000000"], ["restaurant_id", 4], ["updated_at", "2014-07-21 12:06:49.727918"], ["user_id", 7]]
   (6.4ms)  COMMIT

ReservationMailer#reservation_notification: processed outbound mail in 0.6ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `restaurant' for #<Reservation:0x007ffeb0fb8360>:
  activemodel (4.1.4) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:208:in `method_missing'
  app/mailers/reservation_mailer.rb:7:in `reservation_notification'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionmailer (4.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:580:in `block in process'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionmailer (4.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:577:in `process'
  actionmailer (4.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:568:in `initialize'
  actionmailer (4.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:551:in `new'
  actionmailer (4.1.4) lib/action_mailer/base.rb:551:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:21:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.4) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/kareem/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/70365933492240/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-21 07:06:49 -0500
```

Comment: maybe you show Reservation and Restaurant models

Comment: Provide full log and db schema.

Comment: Please provide error message dump

Comment: I just provided it. Many thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurants
end
```

to

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Just curios though, all this time my associations were plural but they worked (id's were inserted automatically). Why is that?